# MySQL query insert current time

Tags: mysql

This format in database:

[image]

Display date some like this:

[image]

Below I have mysql query

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO payment (user_id, course_id, amount, data_added)
SELECT user_id,course_id,monthly_subscription_fee,here_i_need_get_current_time
FROM enrol
WHERE active_shop='1'";
```

Can anyone help me how can I generate current time in the same format as above screen in position `here_i_need_get_current_time`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(1642633200),'%a,%d-%b-%Y');
```

Replace 1642633200 with your column name `date_added`

First you need to convert your date using `FROM_UNIXTIME` and then give your desired format using `DATE_FORMAT`

> Result:
>
> ```
> DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(1642633200),'%a,%d-%b-%Y')
> Wed,19-Jan-2022
> ```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=99edadfefba86e9638e7ce3445c15ae3)

Check [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) doc for more info